# Most efficient way to save result of SQL query in CDS/Dataverse into SQL Database table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-functions, powerapps, dataverse

For the purpose of my application I have created an Azure Function that connects with my Dataverse environment, query data with SELECT from different tables (I create new records based on records in tables A, B, C), stores the result into a list and then saves those records into same Dataverse environment but into another table (lets say D). I decided for such solution because Power Automate was creating those new records too slowly.

It works fine, however when there are too many requests (more than 2-3 users work with application and run Azure Functions) the save into Dataverse begins to be too slow too.

So I am thinking about another way to save and store those records. What important is that those records in table D are only for calculation purpose, users do not work with them or edit them. This is why I am thinking about creating SQL Datables table, store those records (only from table D) there, and just change connection in my application where needed.

Can you suggest me the most efficient way to do this? In a nutshell what I need is:

- connect to Dataverse and query data from tables A, B, C. Result of this query will be records for table D
- save the result of the query into SQL Database table (table D)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things to consider here.

1. If users don't use data of table D, could you maybe run this operation overnight or at a time when there is low traffic and slow performance of this operation is acceptable?
2. Have you considered using SQL views? Do you really need to store the computed data?
3. Perhaps you are inserting 1 item at a time? Are you using the Sql Bulk Copy Class?

   [Bulk Insert In SQL Server From C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-c-sharp)

4. Observe the CPU utilisation of your server during this operation. If probably shoots to 100%. You want to hit 70% average utilisation for good trade-off between performance and cost. So another option is to scale up.

Comment: I feel I want to achieve something similar to @Termigez . I want to start using Dataverse's API for dynamics CRM. However I'm facing a problem where I want to create a SQL view within dataverse. So I don't have to call complex http request everytime.
I read about Saved queries, however I'm not sure how to create them. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi @ItsNotMyFault, I am sorry I don't have knowledge of Dynamics CRM